# Is there a quick method to project points onto an certain grid?

Tags: python, numpy

I am now trying to project n points with 3 dimensional coordinates (x,y,z) onto a xy-grid with a certain size (like 64*64), of course the coordinate of such n points is restricted in this grid.

The goal is to print z coordinate of points which are projected onto each of grid elements. I write two for-loops, but is there any better method to avoid using for-loop to run it more quickly?

```
for i in range(XY_grid.shape[0]):
    x = np.where((X_coordinate > i) & (X_coordinate <= i + 1), 1, 0)
    for j in range(XY_grid.shape[1]):
        y = np.where(( Y_coordinate > j) & (Y_coordinate <= j + 1), 1, 0)  
        print(x * y * Z_coordinate)
```

Comment: What is your aim with the print statement `print(x * y * Z_coordinate)` ?

Comment: What is your input points and grid shape? you are comparing coordinates to integer numbers, does that mean your coordinates are normalized to grid step sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is a 2D histogram:

```
import numpy as np

# generate some data (x, y, z)
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
z = np.arange(100)[::-1] * 1.5

# grid (x, y) onto a defined grid (0-127) in x and y
grid, xe, ye = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(np.arange(128), np.arange(128)), weights=None)

grid.sum()
>>> 100.0 # all data is in the grid (was only 100 points)
```

You can use the `weight` argument to add `z` values:

```
# grid (x, y) onto a defined grid (0-127) in x and y
grid, xe, ye = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(np.arange(128), np.arange(128)), weights=z)

grid.sum()
>>> 7425.0

z.sum()
>>> 7425.0 # all z values are in the produced grid
```

You can change the `bins` widths etc. to make them nonuniform, or keep them evenly spaced for a regular grid.

The resulting `grid` is a 2D numpy array which contains all of the `z` information that falls into each bin. You can easily just `print` it or loop over it to get every element in turn.

Answer (score 0):

To print all the entries of `Z_coordinate` that coorespond to a specific point in `X_coordinate` and `Y_coordinate` you can do:

```py
for i in range(XY_grid.shape[0]):
    for j in range(XY_grid.shape[1]):
        print(Z_coordinate[np.logical_and(X_coordinate==i, Y_coordinate==j)])
```